# Averaging input from django admin form and adding it to model field

Tags: django, forms, admin

In my django admin form I have a number of fields where a user can input floating point numbers.  I'd like to average these numbers and save the average to the model field of a related foreign object when the form is submitted.  What is the best way to do this?

**Edit:**
Based on fest's answer below I tried:

```
class ForeignObject(models.Model):
  avg = models.FloatField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
  foreign_object = models.ForeignKey(ForeignObject)
  field1 = models.FloatField()
  field2 = models.FloatField()
  avg = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

  def save(*args, **kwargs):
    self.foreign_object.avg = float(sum([self.field1, self.field2])) / 2 
    return super(models.Model, self.foreign_object).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But received the exception: `'super' object has no attribute 'save'` when attempting to submit the admin form.

Comment: Please see my updated answer- there was a missing first parameter in save method.

Comment: @fest Haha X).  Still having another issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be:

```
class ForeignObject(models.Model):
  avg = models.FloatField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
  foreign_object = models.ForeignKey(ForeignObject)
  field1 = models.FloatField()
  field2 = models.FloatField()
  avg = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.foreign_object.avg = float(sum([self.field1, self.field2])) / 2 
    self.foreign_object.save()
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This assumes self.foreign_object is already created.
Also, save doesn't return any value, so no return needed.

Answer (score 2):

Set the average value in model's save() method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  field1 = models.FloatField()
  field2 = models.FloatField()
  avg = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.avg = float(sum([self.field1, self.field2])) / 2
    return super(models.Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Most likely you will also want to set `avg` field to be read only- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: `avg` field must be defined with `blank=True` so you can leave the field blank on the form.

Comment: Sorry I had to clarify my question a little.  I meant to say that I wanted to save to the model field of a related foreign object. (A field in its ForeignKey)

Comment: @HighLife doesn't the code snippet above help? Just set the related object's attribute and execute related object's save() method.

Comment: @fest yes, but I'm still having some issues.  `self.foriegnobject.avg = float(sum([self.field1, self.field2])) / 2`     
    `return super(models.Model, self.foriegnobject).save(*args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: @HighLife yes, looks correct. You could update your question with what you've tried to do and explain what issues do you have.